# Replace sublist with another sublist - python

Tags: python, list, replace, sublist

I have a list:

```
Online = [['Robot1', '23.9', 'None', '0'], ['Robot2', '25.9', 'None', '0']]
```

and i want to replace the sublist if i received different values:

```
NewSublist1 =  ['Robot1', '30.9', 'Sending', '440']

NewSublist2 =  ['Robot2', '50']
```

And i want:

```
Online = [['Robot1', '30.9', 'Sending', '440'], ['Robot2', '50']]
```

The number of the sublist elements could change. The only thing that is the same is the Robot id. So i want to make a search, see if the Robot id is on the Online list and replace the sublist with the new one.

Comment: Ok, that sounds straight-forward. What does your code look like, and where are you stuck?

Comment: You want to merge those lists?

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far, and read through the Python tutorial on data structures: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary mapping the `robot` IDs in your new sublists to the actual new sublists, then look up the existing `robot` IDs in that dict and replace accordingly.

```
>>> Online = [['Robot1', '23.9', 'None', '0'], ['Robot3', 'has no replacement'], ['Robot2', '25.9', 'None', '0']]
>>> NewSublists = [['Robot1', '30.9', 'Sending', '440'], ['Robot2', '50'], ['Robot4', 'new entry']]
>>> newsub_dict = {sub[0]: sub for sub in NewSublists}
>>> [newsub_dict.get(sub[0], sub) for sub in Online]
[['Robot1', '30.9', 'Sending', '440'],
 ['Robot3', 'has no replacement'],
 ['Robot2', '50']]
```

This will loop over each element in the list once, giving it a complexity of O(n), n being the number of elements in the `Online` list. If, instead, you make `Online` also a dictionary mapping `robot` IDs to sublists, you could get this down to O(k), k being the number of new sublists.

If you also want to add elements from `NewSublists` to `Online` if those are not yet present, you should *definitely* convert `Online` to a `dict` as well; then you can simply `update` the dict and get the `values`. Ir order matters, make sure to use a `collections.OrderedDict` or Python 3.7.

```
>>> online_dict = {sub[0]: sub for sub in Online}
>>> online_dict.update(newsub_dict)
>>> list(online_dict.values())
[['Robot1', '30.9', 'Sending', '440'],
 ['Robot3', 'has no replacement'],
 ['Robot2', '50'],
 ['Robot4', 'new entry']]
```

Comment: Thanks. One more thing, how to replace the sublist only when the Robot id is on the Online list? When Robot id not present, add the sublist to thge Online list.

Comment: @HugoAguiar See my edit.